# $POST_ to return array from multiple checkbox

Tags: php, html

Hi I have looked at other answers and they said to add name=checkbox[] to get the array to return but it doesn't appear to working.

The HTML is:

```
<select class="select" multiple="multiple" name="suburb[]" id="suburb">
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="Southbank">Southbank</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="Docklands">Docklands</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="South Melbourne">South Melbourne</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="West Melbourne">West Melbourne</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="Point Cook">Point Cook</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="Sanctuary Lakes">Sanctuary Lakes</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="Truganina">Truganina</option>
<option selected="selected" name="suburb[]" value="Williams Landing">Williams Landing</option>
```

PHP code is:

```
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Interested Suburbs:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($POST_['suburb']) . "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$_POST['suburb']
```

Is an array not a string also you mispelled it its $_POST, so you would need to loop through it to post like so:

```
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Interested Suburbs:</strong> </td><td>";

foreach ($_POST['suburb'] as $suburb)
{
    $message .= strip_tags($suburb) . "<br />\n";
}

$message .= "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine: you just need to use `$_POST` and `print_r` the array to see its contents.  Try this, and you'll see it works fine.

By the way, you don't need a `name` attribute on your `options`

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
    <select name="suburb[]" class="select" multiple="multiple" id="suburb">
        <option selected="selected" value="Southbank">Southbank</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Docklands">Docklands</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="South Melbourne">South Melbourne</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="West Melbourne">West Melbourne</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Point Cook">Point Cook</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Sanctuary Lakes">Sanctuary Lakes</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Truganina">Truganina</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Williams Landing">Williams Landing</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">test</button>
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST['suburb']);
?>
```

Comment: PS - temporarily, you can see this in action at  http://www.stevenmoseley.com/test.php - where I tested it

Answer (score 1):

The variable you're looking for is `$_POST`, not `$POST_`; see [the PHP reference on $_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) for more details.

Otherwise, from what you have shown, it's probably fine.  Add the HTML for your form tag as well if things still don't work.